# Django Axes doesn't get failed login attemps in django Oscar

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, axes, django-oscar

I'm working in a e-shop using `django-oscar` and i'm using `django-axes` for login attemps capture.

All is work fine when i get the `django` admin login: if i failed three times, `axes` lock out me.

But when i failed many times in Oscar login i haven't problem to try again and again an again... `axes` never lock out me!

I'm using `django-axes==2.2.0` with this settings:

```
AXES_LOGIN_FAILURE_LIMIT = 3 
AXES_USE_USER_AGENT = True 
AXES_COOLOFF_TIME = 24
```

Can anyone help me?

**Update:**
I did the [documentation](https://django-axes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/issues.html#not-being-locked-out-after-failed-attempts) steps for it and i have two different performances:

- If i put `url(r'^accounts/login/$', watch_login(login.as_view()),
  name='login'),` watcher doesn't catch the failed login attepms. I put
  this because `Oscar`'s default login url is this, `login/` url
  doesn't exist in `Oscar`. If i put `url(r'^login/$',
  watch_login(login.as_view()), name='login'),`, watcher catch the
  failed login attemp, but only in `login/` url, that here is a new url
  as say before, but in the `Oscar`'s default login url watcher doesn't
  catch this attepms.

Can anyone explain me why happen this?

Comment: This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-axes) under "*Not being locked out after failed attempts*". You probably just need to follow those instructions. It will not be picking up Oscar's custom login URLs automatically.

Comment: And so...
I want that both, `django-admin` and `oscar login` be watching by `django-axes`.